# mac shortcuts to go to finder and open terminal

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, finder

are there any keyboard shortcuts that would take the cursor to finder?
what open launching a terminal window?

Comment: "what open launching a terminal window?" -- what does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think I quite understand your question. Do you want to open a terminal using the keyboard only? Do you want to open finder and THEN open a terminal in that finder’s location, all using a keyboard?

If you want to open the terminal, just use spotlight (or Launchbar).

If you want to open the finder, you can always cmd-tab to the finder, cmd-n for a new window, navigate to where you want to go and then use [Shell Here](http://etresoft.org/shellhere.html) (assignate a keyboard shortcut for it).

Using [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html) is probably way easier and more powerful than any other method.